# How to write empty element with StAX?

Tags: xml, stax

I'm using StAX in order to write an XML document but I can't find how to write the empty elements XML.  I would like to write `<element/>` instead of `<element></element>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use writeEmptyElement method in XMLStreamWriter class: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamWriter.html#writeEmptyElement%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: Damn, it was in the Javadoc! Thank you for the quick response!